# Can the Fedora installer partition the disk itself?

Tags: fedora, partition

I've been using Ubuntu for a little while now, but I plan on dual-booting with Fedora just to try it. Does Fedora give you the option to partition your disk and dual boot upon installation or do I have to partition the disk before I go into installation?

Comment: Making a list of how Fedora is different from Ubuntu isn't really what we're here for. I edited to include just the concrete question

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both of your questions. Probably the most intelligent way to do this is to partition according to your needs in a pre-installation-kickstart-file.

Use `parted` for this...

Answer (score 0):

The Fedora installer has a step in which you can modify and resize partitions with a GParted-like interface.

You can choose to have Fedora reinstall the GRUB bootloader, overwriting the existing one from Ubuntu. Following this, GRUB will have entries for both Fedora and Ubuntu when you reboot.